# css transition on grid-row-end

Tags: css, transition

I'm trying to and a transition to a grid-row-end change.  Is there a way to do it?  I tried using the below to no effect.

```
.box {
     transition: grid-row-end 2s ease;
     transition: height 2s ease;
}
```

The change happens when clicked on.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43911880/3597276

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how you want this grid or how you want to manipulate it, I'm not familiar with grids but:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
        .container{
              display: grid;
              grid-template: 100px 1fr / 50px 1fr;
              max-height: 600px;
        }
        .box {
             transition: grid-row-end 2s ease, height 2s ease;
             border: 2px solid black;
             height: 200px;
             width: 100px;
             grid-row-end: 1;
        }
        .box:hover{
            height: 300px;
            grid-row-end: 4;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class = "container">
    <div class="box">
        <p>test</p>
     </div>
     </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

The `container` div has the grid template which you can manipulate to your liking.
The box has the transitions on one line with your `grid-row-end` and `height` transitions along with the `width` and `height` AND `grid-row-end` that you have to manipulate. **HOWEVER** this is your starting point, so keep that in mind.
And as for the `.box:hover`, that would be your ending point technically.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Since the grid is dynamic, setting the size doesn't work.  I just want to increase the grid from 2 rows to 3 rows and have it animate/transition to the new height but it looks like grids aren't keyed into transition yet.  :(

Comment: Again not good with grids but I got it so that it has six entries. Starts with two rows and three columns but moves to three rows and two columns. You'd have to make your specific adjustments (e: fixed the drag)

https://jsfiddle.net/35vbcwng/