# animating a smooth css grid-column change

Tags: css, animation, css-grid

I am using CSS grid layout to position various parts on a website. I use `grid-column: x / x;` and `grid-row x / x;` to set their position and size on the page. It's working really well.

Now I am trying to animate a smooth transition between two grid-column fixes which happens when the screen size changes. The change is from `grid-column: 3 / 9;` to `grid-column: 2 / 10;` which means the div grows on either side by `1fr` each. At the moment it just "pings" into place but I would like to have a smooth transition between the two.

Anybody got any ideas how to tackle it?

Here is the snippet from my CSS file:

```
nav {
    background-color: $company-blue;
    border          : 3px solid $company-yellow;
    opacity         : 0.8;
    grid-column     : 3 / 9;
    grid-row        : 3 / 4;
    ...
    @media screen and (max-width: 1378px) {
    grid-column : 2 / 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: transition ? but if it works, it will be buggy . CSS won't help you here i believe.

Comment: Can you please add all relevant HTML and CSS to your question?

Comment: I don't think major browsers support transitions for Grid at the moment. https://stackoverflow.com/q/43911880/3597276

Comment: Thanks Michael_B, I see you had the same issue. Shame that grid layouts can't be animated. If you find anything else out I would love to hear about it. In the mean time I'll have to use JS, I guess.

Answer (score 7):

There are no CSS transitions for `grid-column` or `grid-row` properties. In order to have any,

```
grid-column: 2.5 / 9.5;
```

...would have to make sense from a rendering point of view.
Imagine you're the guy coding the browser. How  would you render a `grid-column:2.5 / 9.5;`?

Expecting CSS transitions to work here is like expecting them to work in CSS columns when content moves between columns.

Need animations with CSS Grid? JavaScript is your only friend.

Here's how I'd go about it:

1. clone contents of each grid element into absolutely positioned containers.
2. fade real content out, using opacity
3. apply the new `grid-columns` property to the grid
4. animate cloned elements into new positions of real ones
5. fade cloned content out and the real one back in
6. delete clones.

Making this work cross-browser/cross-device might pose a few problems, but it's doable.

**Note:** You might want to consider adding a layer of wrappers between the contents of your grid elements and the grid elements, to help with two things:

1. make sure each grid element has only one child (to simplify getting the width/height for calculating transition)
2. simplify tracking each element so you know what to transition where

Comment: Hi Andrei, I had a feeling that would be the case. JS it is then :) Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

I've cheated it with a very poor hack. But it works...

```
nav {
    background-color: $company-blue;
    border          : 3px solid $company-yellow;
    opacity         : 0.8;
    grid-column     : 3 / 9;
    grid-row        : 3 / 4;
    @media screen and (max-width: 1378px) {
        position   : fixed;
        z-index    : 9999;
        width      : 60%;
        margin     : 155px 20% 0;
        animation  : grow-fixed 1s ease;
        @keyframes grow-fixed {
            0% {
                width : 60%;
                margin: 155px 20% 0;
            }

            100% {
                width : 80%;
                margin: 155px 10% 0;
            }
        }
        width      : 80%;
        margin     : 155px 10% 0;
        grid-column: 2 / 10;
        grid-row   : 3 / 4;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 1378px) {
        position   : fixed;
        z-index    : 9999;
        width      : 80%;
        margin     : 155px 10% 0;
        animation  : shrink-fixed 1s ease;
        @keyframes shrink-fixed {
            0% {
                width : 80%;
                margin: 155px 10% 0;
            }

            100% {
                width : 60%;
                margin: 155px 20% 0;
            }
        }
        width      : 60%;
        margin     : 155px 20% 0;
        grid-column: 3 / 9;
        grid-row   : 3 / 4;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really difficult doing it all by your self even when you are using javascript. So I would recommend using this library unfortunately you cant use this with plain html so you must have a react or vue project.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/animate-css-grid

React Example:

codepen.io/aholachek/pen/mxwvmV

Vue example:

codepen.io/sustained/pen/Rwbdgob

Comment: Using that library, how would they solve their problem? Suggesting a library is fine, but you should still offer e.g., sample code for how to solve the immediate problem.

Comment: @JeremyCaney I though that examples the creators had given were enough for the problem and I probably should have linked the codepens earlier, but you could also find it on the npm site. Also I was just trying to give my two cents to the problem.

Comment: Ideally, answers should include more than a link or a suggested library. Often, the links change, the samples are updated, or members unfamiliar with a library aren’t sure how to adapt the examples to their specific problem. Given that, we strive for answers that address the immediate problem, are self-sufficient, and will hopefully continue to be useful to readers over time.

Comment: case in point: the links no longer work