# Can I animate CSS Grid Layout components?

Tags: reactjs, css, animation, css-grid

Is there a way to animate a changed order of components in an array that are displayed with a CSS Grid layout?

here is a short [boilerplate](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-91sclc)

Comment: [Useful link](https://codepen.io/matuzo/post/animating-css-grid-layout-properties) for you (FF only)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43911880/3597276

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## NO.

> According to the [**CSS Grid Layout Module Level 1 specification**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/) there are 5 animatable grid properties:
>
> `grid-gap, grid-row-gap, grid-column-gap`
>   as length, percentage, or calc
>
> `grid-template-columns, grid-template-rows`
>   as a simple list of length, percentage, or calc, provided the only differences are the values of the length, percentage, or calc components in the list.
>
> <sup>[Source](https://codepen.io/matuzo/post/animating-css-grid-layout-properties)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the user to see change of text, you can let a javascript, replace the text of each div. In this case, the divs will be the same though (e.g. div-1, div-2, div-3). You would only change the text.

If you want to change position of complete div + content (in html) and its css properties to change then you will have to expand the javascript to have a function that takes 3 values and randomly put them in order, (say, 1,3,2). Through the javascript you can then delete and create divs based on need.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, supported in Firefox v66