# Filter items CSS grid position re-adjusment animations

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

I have a react app that filters a bunch of items in a css grid layout.

When un-filtered  the grid contains all the items.

```
<div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
<div>
```

Once a filtered is applied the grid of items will get smaller

```
<div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
<div>
```

If another filter is removed there may be more.

```
<div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
<div>
```

How can I apply transition animations for grid items to slide into place when grid items disappear or reappear?

Comment: Basically, not possible - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47905017/css-grid-animations

Answer (score -2):

I made a package that controls a components animation dynamicly. Basicaly it enables you to animate a components movement(and more) from 1 place it was rendered to another. The component main idea is that you give it a singularKey and a singularPriority and when a the component is rendered serval times(the component is identified by the singularKey) it will only render the instance with the highest singularPriority and animate from the last rendered instance postion and dimensions. For cases like yours, where the use case is very similar but you only need to render the component at one place, I added an animationTrigger prop that when changed cause the component to animate from its previous state.

Here is the package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-singular-component

Here is the example: https://dor6.github.io/react-singular-component/

Look at the list example, its a very similar case to yours. You can add an item to the top of the list or delete an item anywhere in the list. I used the items index as an animationTrigger and by doing so whenever an items index changes the item will animate.

You can also look at the list example code on github: https://github.com/dor6/react-singular-component/blob/master/examples/src/listExample.js

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231) (also see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/271271)). You should expand your answer to include as much information here as possible, like the example you link, and use the links only for reference. Basically, posts on Stack Overflow (and all of Stack Exchange) must be self-contained. That means that enough information needs to be in your answer such that the reader doesn't *need to* go off-site for directions. Right now, that's not the case for this answer. Right now, this is, at best, of limited usability.