# CSS grid use min-content as a base for 1 fr unit

Tags: css, css-grid

Here is the layout that I'm working on (https://codepen.io/tomaszal/pen/QWWJPRQ):

```css
body {
  height: calc(100vh - 2rem);
  margin: 1rem;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  
  grid-template-columns: [c1] 1fr [c2] 1fr [c3];
  grid-template-rows: [r1] min-content [r2] auto [r3] auto [r4];
}

body > div { padding: 1rem; }

.fill { background-color: green; }
.narrow { background-color: orange; }

.f1 { grid-area: r1 / c1 / r3; }
.f2 { grid-area: r2 / c2 / r4; }
.n1 { grid-area: r3 / c1 / r4; }
.n2 { grid-area: r1 / c2 / r2; }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="fill f1">Fill all available height (auto)</div>
  <div class="fill f2">Fill all available height (auto)</div>
  <div class="narrow n1">Mimic n2 height (1fr of min-content?)</div>
  <div class="narrow n2">Some text with unknown height (min-content)</div>
</body>
```

I'm trying to make the bottom orange div be the same height of the top orange div. If I could use min-content as a base for 1 fr unit I could just say something like this:

```
grid-template-rows: [r1] (min-content, 1fr) [r2] auto [r3] 1fr [r4];
```

Is there any sane way of doing this? I've tried the following:

```
grid-template-rows: [r1] 1fr [r2] auto [r3] 1fr [r4];
grid-template-rows: [r1] 1fr [r2] max-content [r3] 1fr [r4];
grid-template-rows: [r1] 1fr [r2] min-content [r3] 1fr [r4];
```

However these do not produce the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

A hacky idea is to initially make both of them on the same row so they can get the same height then translate the left column to get the final output

```css
body {
  height: calc(100vh - 2rem);
  margin: 1rem;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: min-content  auto;
}

body > div { padding: 1rem; }

.fill { background-color: green; }
.narrow { background-color: orange;order:-1 }

/* Remove the below to see the output before the translate*/
.n1 {
  transform:translateY(calc((100vh - 2rem) - 100%))
}
.f1 {
  transform:translateY(calc(100% - (100vh - 2rem)))
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="fill f1">Fill all available height (auto)</div>
  <div class="fill f2">Fill all available height (auto)</div>
  <div class="narrow n1">Mimic n2 height (1fr of min-content?)</div>
  <div class="narrow n2">Some text with <br> unknown height <br>(min-content)</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is a very cool solution. The only problem right now is when the parent (body in this case) is not of a fixed hight. I'm trying right now to use absolute positioning to sort of mimic this hack.

Comment: @Tomaszal I don't think you can get it with position:absolute because it will remove the element from the flow, Will try to find another idea

Comment: Yeah you are right, absolutely positioned element no longer abides to the grid sizing. I could probably use your initial suggestion with JS to get the parent's height, but hopefully we can figure out a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might not be possible to do this with CSS only. Here's a solution using JS and CSS variables that does exactly what I want (https://codepen.io/tomaszal/pen/rNNQggO):

```js
unique = document.getElementById("unique");

new ResizeSensor(unique, function() {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--unique-height', `${unique.clientHeight}px`);
});
```

```css
body {
  height: calc(100vh - 2rem);
  margin: 1rem;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  
  grid-template-columns: [c1] 1fr [c2] 1fr [c3];
  grid-template-rows: [r1] min-content [r2] auto [r3] var(--unique-height, auto) [r4];
}

body > div { padding: 1rem; }

.fill { background-color: green; }
.narrow { background-color: orange; }

.f1 { grid-area: r1 / c1 / r3; }
.f2 { grid-area: r2 / c2 / r4; }
.n1 { grid-area: r3 / c1 / r4; }
.n2 { grid-area: r1 / c2 / r2; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css-element-queries/1.2.1/ResizeSensor.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="fill f1">Fill all available height (auto)</div>
  <div class="fill f2">Fill all available height (auto)</div>
  <div class="narrow n1">Mimics n2 height</div>
  <div class="narrow n2" id="unique">
    Some text with unknown unique height (min-content)
    <br/><br/>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </div>
</body>
```

This is obviously not ideal (any JS doing tasks that should be done by CSS is not), however it's better than nothing for now.

Comment: here you go, that's a tipycal js jobs to retrieve an unknown height ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr Should I accept this as an answer though? It feels a bit hacky to me.

Comment: **it is the answer,**, js is not hacky, js is about the king of the apps . it's everywhere. ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr The hacky bit is that you have to wait for JS to run before these changes to take effect. It results in a jumpy page load and is why pure CSS solutions are always better. I'm trying to figure out how to do grid transitions right now to animate the jumpines and make it a little less jarring, but that's obviously a completely different question.

Comment: would CSS transition do the thing ? https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zYYMVLd

Comment: Unfortunately CSS transitions (do not work in this case)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911880/using-css-transitions-in-css-grid-layout]. The easiest solution is to smootly change the --unique-height with JS, I'm just looking for a library that could help me with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202492/discussion-between-tomaszal-and-g-cyr).

Comment: instead `var(--unidue-height,auto)` you need `var(--unidue-height,0)` 0 or any other value , so the transition can go through steps  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zYYMVLd updated