# Make side bars reducing with max-width by degrees

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

How to make side parts of web page reduce they width with reducing width of whole page by degrees?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 10% 80% 10%;
            min-height: 100vh;
        }
        .side-right {
            background: red;
        }
        .side-left {
            background: blue;
        }
        .main {
            background: green;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
            .container {
                grid-template-columns: 0 100% 0;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="side-right">
    </div>
    <div class="main">
    </div>
    <div class="side-left">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In example below after max-width = 1000px side elements are dissapearing instantly, but I want to make them reducing they width reacting by every pixel changed on max-width. How to make it?

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911880/using-css-transitions-in-css-grid-layout) post it's hard to achieve this with the grid-layout. Maybe try using flex-layout.

Comment: No problem, but how to make that using flex-layout? Actually I don't know hot to do that in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly...change the initial `grid-template-columns` to

```
  grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(1000px, 8fr) 1fr;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(1000px, 8fr) 1fr;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.side-right {
  background: red;
}

.side-left {
  background: blue;
}

.main {
  background: green;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 0 1fr 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="side-right">
  </div>
  <div class="main">
  </div>
  <div class="side-left">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can animate all with `flex-box` and just by changing some of your css.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.side-right {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}
.side-left {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
.main {
  background: green;
  min-width: 600px;
}
```

Thats just a basic example. Consider reading more about flex-box.

Comment: Looks like I'm not clear. I wanted to say that that side elements must behave like on that website "https://edukacja.pwr.wroc.pl/EdukacjaWeb/studia.do". Just try to press f12 and resize width of the page. And see how behave background of side elements

Comment: Okay now I know what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `min-with: 50px;` to `.side-right` and `.side-left`
And then give them both an `z-index: 1;`
So they wont lay under your main

Hope that helps