# Is there a way to animate an element from one grid cell to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-grid

I would like to have an element slide over to another grid cell. I had assumed it would be easy using jQuery's `.animate()` method, but you cannot change the grid CSS through there. You also cannot use the `.css()` method, because then it just snaps into place and it does not slide into place.

Is there an easy way to do this with CSS and javascript/jQuery? Is there another API I could be using to make this easier? I honestly don't know where to start.

Comment: Please read [ask], [edit] adding a [mcve].

Comment: Basically no. Css-grid position is not animatable like that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911880/using-css-transitions-in-css-grid-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of to sort of do this is to almost fake it?  Get the current x/y coordinates of the box, put it into it's new position, get the new x/y coordinates, snap it back, animate it using `position: relative`, and then once the animation is done, take off the relative positioning and update it back to the right coordinates.

Something like this:

```js
const b = document.getElementById('b');
document.getElementById('demo').addEventListener('click', function() {
    const { top: top1, left: left1 } = b.getBoundingClientRect();
    b.style.transition = '2s';
    b.style['grid-row-start'] = 3;
    b.style['grid-row-end'] = 4;
    const { top: top2, left: left2 } = b.getBoundingClientRect();
    b.style['grid-row-start'] = 2;
    b.style['grid-row-end'] = 3;
    setTimeout(() => {
        b.style.transition = 'auto';
        b.style['grid-row-start'] = 3;
        b.style['grid-row-end'] = 4;
        b.style.top = 0;
        b.style.left = 0;
    }, 2000);
    
    b.style.left = (left2 - left1) + 'px';
    b.style.top = (top2 - top1) + 'px';
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 2s;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.a {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}
.b {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
.c {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
.d {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}
.e {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
.f {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}
```

```html
<button id="demo">Click Me</button>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div id="b" class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't use your exact code, but I used your general concept. I first used getBoundingClientRect() to get the current dimensions and position of the image, and then I saved it to variables. Then, I got rid of the CSS that kept the image in that specific grid cell, so the image snapped to the top left of the grid. Then, I was able to use `top` and `left` to move the image back to its original position using the variables I created getBoundingClientRect() to get the size of the grid cells, and then animated it 1 grid cell width to the left. Thanks! :)