# Best Animation Option for this situation

Tags: javascript, css, transition

I am trying to find out the best way to edit the transition between two states of CSS. I'm open to any suggestions. I am not super experienced with Javascript but am looking for some suggestions on where to look to get information or if I'm going about this in the completely wrong way. Anything will help.

So effectively I have javascript add a class to a div that will then change the CSS of that div when the class is applied. I'm looking for a way to transition between these two CSS states somewhat smoothly. Maybe I'm trying to find a "too simple" method of doing this, but this is the only thing that has worked for me.

Here is the code I'm currently using on playcode.io:
https://playcode.io/650950

A CSS option would be preferable, but I think that this is outside of CSS's capabilities.

Thanks for any help in advance. :)

Comment: jQuery UI has been really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into the transition property in css. It does exactly what you need, animate a change in another css property.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: I have tried that, but could you give me some insight into how to implement it? It only does a transition on some of the elements and not others. Also the height is an issue, I'd like it to grow in size, but I don't have the height defined so the content will only take up the space it needs.

Comment: Sorry, just looked into it and apparently only Firefox has correctly implemented transitions for grid properties, even if they are part of the spec.

Here's a related post with alternatives  on how to animate grid layouts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911880/using-css-transitions-in-css-grid-layout

Comment: Regarding height, you are right, without a set height the property is not animateable. The solution that comes to mind  is not a simple one as you are looking for. 

Through js you have to check the element's height after it renders and then set the element's height to that value.

After that setup, when you are changing the content of the element, you remove the height so it can grow naturally, you read the height property again and finally set it to that value.

You will probably have to use requestAnimationFrame to time those property reads and writes correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but after some research and messing with other javascript libraries. I found it to be more effective to use jQuery animate() functionality. I could never wrap my head around how to do it in vanilla javascript, but jQuery simplifies it. It is restrictive, but looks like it will fit the bill.