# How to use transitions with grid-row and grid-column changes

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my website I use gridbox for the whole page. I have a set of buttons inside of a div that start off in a certain grid location, and then on the click of the "Start Game" button I change their location. I do this by using a js function that changes the element's `grid-row` and `grid-column`. Now I want to add a transition effect to this change in `grid-row` and `grid-column`. Make it ease in a bit. How would I do this?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="main">
    <div id="menu">
        <button class="btn" id="start_btn" onclick="moveMenu();startGame();this.disabled = true;">Start Game!</button>
        <button class="btn" onclick="endTurn();">End Turn</button>
        <button class="btn" onclick="endGame();">End Game</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Relevant CSS

```
#main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 20vh 5vh 10vh repeat(3, 10.56vh) 10vh 10vh 20vh;
    grid-template-columns: 10vw repeat(6, 12vw) 18vw;
    grid-gap: .5vh;
    background-color: #fffcf4;
}

#menu {
    grid-row: 3/8;
    grid-column: 4/7;
    transition: 2s;
}
```

Relevant JS

```
function moveMenu() {
    var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
    menu.style.gridRow = '1/2';
    menu.style.gridColumn = '1/2'; 
}
```

Comment: You can't. Those properties are not animatable

Comment: @Paulie_D Any alternatives? Should I disable the grid properties on click and then do floating positioning which I know can be used with transitions?

Comment: Yeah your best luck would be with flex or float and change layout based on elements width as grid display is not animatable.

Comment: According to the [flex spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#property-index), the `flex-order` property is animatable. I don't know how much flexibility that gives you. You can make each row in your grid a flexbox, though, rather than trying to mess with wrapping a flex onto multiple rows. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911880/using-css-transitions-in-css-grid-layout) is a good post for just what you can and can't animate on a grid. (Try the code in the accepted answer in both Chrome and Firefox.)