# How can I add transition when changing CSS grid by using JS AddClass Function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to figure out. How can I make the transition a bit nicer. As you can see my demo here which is a hero section.
When hovering the first Div, the container will be added a class. which is going to change to another grid.
Border color does have transition 1s, but the grid does not.
Is it possible to do it for grid?

Thanks

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {     
    $('.er-hero__1 .er-hero__item:nth-of-type(1)').hover(
      function(){     
        $('.er-hero__1').addClass('er-hero__1--1');    
      },     
      function(){    
        $('.er-hero__1').removeClass('er-hero__1--1');     
      });
  });  
});
```

```css
.er-hero__item {
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
    text-align: left;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    background-color: #777777;
    border-top:10px solid #fff;
    border-right:10px solid #fff;
    }
.er-hero__1 {
    height: 200px;
    border: 10px solid blue;  
    transition: 1s;
}
.er-hero__1 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto;
    }
    .er-hero__1 > :nth-child(1) {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 5;
    }
    .er-hero__1 > :nth-child(2) {
    grid-area: 1 / 5 / 5 / 9;
    }
    .er-hero__1 > :nth-child(3) {
    grid-area: 3 / 1 / 5 / 4;
    }
    .er-hero__1 > :nth-child(4) {
    grid-area: 3 / 4 / 5 / 7;
    }

.er-hero__1--1 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto;
     border: 10px solid red;       
    }
    .er-hero__1--1 > :nth-child(1) {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 5 / 5;
    }
    .er-hero__1--1 > :nth-child(2) {
    grid-area: 1 / 7 / 5 / 9;
    }
    .er-hero__1--1 > :nth-child(3) {
    grid-area: 1 / 5 / 3 / 7;
    }
    .er-hero__1--1 > :nth-child(4) {
    grid-area: 3 / 5 / 5 / 7;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="er-hero__1">
  <div class="er-hero__item"></div>
  <div class="er-hero__item"></div>
  <div class="er-hero__item"></div>
  <div class="er-hero__item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Grid properties are not animatable, so NO.

Comment: Ar... This is sad.... OK Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43921717/1533592